# Boost converter Ic extremely heats up when trying to switch using Mosfet

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost, mosfet-driver, powermosfet, overheat

[image: Mosfet as a switch for boost converter]

In Case 1, the converter works fine but in the other case it heats up extremely.
Tried same using a PNP nosfet and it heats up the same as soon as load is connected.
12v 1A router is used as a load for boost converter

The mosfet is biased using a 9v supply and a 1k resistor.
Mosfet is Irf Z44n

Comment: `PNP` applies to a BJT and not a MOSFET. Try shorting the N channel MOSFET out to see if the booster still works. If it doesn't then the booster can be regarded as faulty. Please state the input voltage and show the circuit of the booster. What is the inrush current of the load like?

Comment: Yeah I meant to say P channel but mistakenly wrote Pnp.Yeah the boost works fine when the intended switching mechanism comprising of Mosfet is removed.It handles the load efficiently without noticeable heating.

Comment: Try shorting out the MOSFET rather than removing it just to be 100%. State your input supply voltage and show your booster circuit or link to a device. The inrush current of your router is probably the culprit as I'll explain in an answer below.

Comment: Hi Andy.The input supply comes from two 18650s in series protected by a bms so it will be around 6v-8.4v

Comment: My answer should give you food for thought on why the IRFZ44 is probably not good enough (even though I assumed a 4 volt supply and an unspecified booster) given the input current and the inrush current preventing a decent kick-off.

Comment: Without properly labeled schematic I can only guess. Two things come to mind, the MOSFET is not capable of driving the load or you are not driving the MOSFET properly. Show the control circuit or at a minimum what it is outputting. I have done this many times without any problems.

Comment: Hi Gil, for gate control I've used a 1k resitor with a 9v supply, so Vgs is slightly less than 9 volts. The boost converter is Xl6009E1 and I am trying to drive a Huawei Fiber router rated at 12v 1A. The mosfet I've used is Irf Z44n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the face of it an IRFZ44 MOSFET seems quite suitable for dealing with a 1 amp load: -

[image]

With a 8 volt gate drive voltage, the MOSFET will conduct and produce a volt drop of about 55 mV. However, the 1 amp load is at 12 volts and your circuit uses a booster to generate 12 volts from (let's say) 4 volts.

Now, the input current to the booster will be 2.5 amps (100% efficiency) or quite likely 3 amps for typical device.

So, with 3 amps flowing through the MOSFET the volt drop will be 0.1 volts and that loses 0.1 volts to the input of the booster and that requires more current on the input and you are close to things running away and getting rather hot.

Added to this is the inrush current of the load that maybe 5 or 10 times the normal running current and you have a situation that can never work.

Solution - pick a MOSFET with much lower on resistance.

Comment: Thankyou Andy. I will look into it and use some other Mosfet with smaller Rds on

Comment: @RojanBhattarai please [take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand the motivation behind folk giving their time freely to help.

Comment: Sorry Andy, it's my 1st time asking a question here. Next time I will totally follow these guidelines.

Comment: @RojanBhattarai no problem, you did things right.